# Beautiful soup getting all <li> tags after specific <br> tag

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to get all the Key Ingredients for all the products under a category, [This web page](https://www.1mg.com/otc/dettol-original-bathing-soap-bar-125gm-each-buy-4-get-1-free-otc587797) shows how the products ingredients are listed, as you can see in the below page source screenshot all the Ingredients are after the br tag with value "Key Ingredients:"
Below is my code, I am able to get the all the text but how can I get all the

tags right after the "Key Ingredients:" 
 tag.

expected output:

```
Glycerin
Sodium Palmate
Sodium Palm Kemelate
Cymbopogon Flexuosus Oil
Linalool
Coumarin
Benzyl Salicylate
Citral
```

Code:

```
from os.path  import basename
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

baseurl = "https://www.1mg.com/otc/dettol-original-bathing-soap-bar-125gm-each-buy-4-get-1-free-otc587797"

header = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) '
                  'Chrome/74.0.3729.169 Safari/537.36 '
}

r = requests.get(baseurl, headers=header)
# soup = BeautifulSoup(r, 'lxml')
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser")
job_element = soup.find("div", class_="otc-container")
categories = job_element.findAll("a", class_="button-text Breadcrumbs__breadcrumb___XuCvk", href=True)
# print(categories)

description = job_element.find("div", class_="ProductDescription__description-content___A_qCZ")
print(description.text)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way could be to isolate the the key ingredients marker - move to the next tag (`<br>`) - then process all following tags until you reach the next `<br>` tag.

```
<strong>Key Ingredients:</strong>
<br>
<ul>
...
...
<ul>
<br>
```

code:

```
>>> for tag in description.find(string='Key Ingredients:').find_next('br').next_elements:
...     if tag.name == 'br': break
...     if tag.name == 'li': tag.get_text()
'Glycerin'
'Sodium Palmate'
'Sodium Palm Kemelate'
'Cymbopogon Flexuosus Oil'
'Linalool'
'Coumarin'
'Benzyl Salicylate'
'Citral'
```

Comment: Awesome, I didnt knew we could loop through the tags too, I started learning Beautiful soup couple of weeks back. Thanks

Comment: There's various examples in [the docs](https://beautiful-soup-4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#navigating-the-tree) which may be of help.